# C# Convert 8 bit mono WAV to MP3 using NAudio.Lame makes ZERO byte file

Tags: c#, mp3, wav, naudio

Trying to convert 8 bit mono (no riff header) WAV to a MP3 that will play in all browsers. I am using:
    using NAudio.Wave;
    using NAudio.Lame;

```
        string wavFile = @"C:\SOUNDBOX\" + message.MessageFileName;
        string tempmp3 = message.MessageFileName.Replace(".wav", ".mp3");
        string mp3FileName = @"C:\SOUNDBOX\play\" + tempmp3;
        if (!File.Exists(mp3FileName)) 
        { 
        var reader = new WaveFileReader(wavFile);

        using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(mp3FileName, reader.WaveFormat, LAMEPreset.VBR_90)) 
        reader.CopyTo(writer);

        }

        context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("https://robotalker.com/soundbox/play/" + tempmp3));
```

I end up with the files being created but they are empty.

Comment: Any difference if you send `128` as the last parameter to this lame constructor? Also, the reader is disposable as well, so wrap it with a `using` statement, and make sure you delete empty files before retrying the code, since the files won't be overwritten with that code, as they already exist.

Comment: I tried the 128 for the first hour. I also check to see if file exists then have cleanup code to remove older than 3 days old. Any more ideas?

Comment: using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(wavFile))
            using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(mp3FileName,     reader.WaveFormat, 128)) 
            reader.CopyTo(writer);  
    No cange

Comment: Now I get this :
 using (var rdr = new WaveFileReader(reader))    {"Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header"}

Comment: Make sure your WAV file isn't corrupt.

Comment: Last night I found out that the WAV files the system makes, that are playable and work just find for broadcasting do not have a RIFF header.  SO I guess now I want to know how to work around converting a 8 bit mono WAV (RIFF-less) to a small MP3 for browser compatibility.